# Apache Rewrite to folder no longer working after server upgrade

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, centos

The following were both working perfectly for the last 2 years but after a server upgrade the first, with an extra folder is no longer working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mayoaccommodation\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mayoaccommodation\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mayo-ireland.ie/accommodation/$1  [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mayobb\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mayobb\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mayo-ireland.ie/accommodation_bb.htm [P]
```

Has there been a change in the rewrite module?

Comment: What upgrade was done?  Versions?

Comment: Stephen, as far as I know just changed to Plesk 11, I can get more info tomorrow.

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled? (run 'a2enmod rewrite;service apache2 reload' if Debian/Ubuntu to enable).

Comment: We've gone from Centos 5.2 > 6.3. And Apache/2.2.3 > Apache/2.2.15

Comment: Yes mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: What exactly do you meany by "no longer working"? You're doing a reverse proxy to serve content from one domain through another domain. That's what appears to be happening with both mayobb and myoaccommodation. There seem to be some randomized content changes (the city list and the banner ad order), but opening both the source domain (mayo-ireland.ie) and the proxy domains in different browsers, I can see the same exact content combinations being shown on both the source and the proxies. So the content proxying seems to be working.

Comment: Though `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassMatch` are preferred over `mod_rewrite` for this type of work, and I'd consider better site architecture (no need for so many domains that are essentially just subsections/directories of the same site). You're going to receive content duplication penalties, as well as making the site less maintainable. Just use a single domain and you can concentrate your SEO efforts in one place and not worry about reverse proxying issues that don't appear to add any value.